# Load application.properties into test xml file

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have a class similar to below

```
public class MyClass {

    String userName;
    String password;

}
```

I am using xml configuration so I have the bean defined in an xml file.

```
</bean>
    <bean name="myclass" class="com.package.MyClass">
    <property name="userName" value="${username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
</bean>
```

This looks in application.properties for username and password. I am currently using getters/setters.

I have a test class like below

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/test.xml")
public class MyTestClass {

    @Autowired
    MyClass

}
```

And in that test.xml file I am defining the same bean like below.

```
</bean>
    <bean name="myclass" class="com.package.MyClass">
    <property name="userName" value="${username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
</bean>
```

However username and password aren't grabbed from application.properties in the test class. Ideally I would like it to grab from an environment specific properties file, but I haven't even figured out how to get it to grab from application.properties. Am I going about this wrong? I am not used to xml configuration.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's wrong to use an XML configuration, but personally I haven't used this for well over ten years, the annotations make it far easier.  Without knowing more about your configuration, you probably just need to annotate your test with the location of your `application.properties`, because you probably don't have a property resolver bean being created. 
 Try adding `@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application.properties")` to your test class.

Comment: I didnt want to use this but unfortunately its the project constraints